# Match a string if maximally two characters differ

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have a list with different names called list.txt. I would like to check if a name already exists in this list. However, I would like to account for a bit of user typing error and capitals (i.e., typing "Jeffersen" instead of "Jefferson", or "Muller" instead of "Müller"). I know that capitals can be ignored in the grep -i command (see underneath). Is there a (grep) shell command where one can also set the number of characters that may differ maximally? For ex. max 2 character differences should be allowed, which means that "Müller" would still be found if "Mueller" were typed).

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Type in name"
read prompt
p=/my-directory-to-listfile/
grep -i "$prompt" /$p/list.txt
```

Comment: Interesting... I don't think `grep` allows you to do so. I would go for `awk`, looping through each single character and keeping a counter of characters that differ.

Comment: You need [`agrep` or Perl's `soundex` Module](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79377/is-there-a-unix-command-that-searches-for-similar-strings-based-mostly-on-how-t).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Agrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/agrep) (approximate grep) should work for you, or use a [levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) implementation. Most languages has it.

Comment: Thank you for these great advices! Indeed agrep does the job: -2 means within up to two errors, -i means to ignore cases:

    `agrep -2 -i "$prompt" /$p/list.txt`